# Channel Images on Amazon S3 is not retrieving the pertinent images

Tags: channel-images, s3

Product (Add-On): Channel Images
Product (Add-On) Version: 5.4.9

ExpressionEngine Version: 2.7.2
MSM Install?: No

After updating Channel Images to 5.4.9 in order to mitigate a bug present in its implementation with Zenbu, I've run into a new issue. When uploading content with Channel Images, my images are able to be uploaded to their buckets, but the system is not seeing them on the other side. I just uploaded a bunch of images in a test entry, verified they existed on the correct bucket, but went to check on the control panel, and the system says it can't find the images! Any idea what's going on there? This is a definite blocker for me and my client right now.

Comment: Hmm, I just updated to the same configuration myself and things seem to be working fine?  

Are you not seeing them in the front end, back end or both?  Maybe share some template code?

Comment: We just had to roll back to 5.4.8 due to a slightly similar issue. It seems C-I isn't applying the S3 endpoint to the files and s3 is rejecting the request.

Comment: Keith, it has nothing to do with the template code. It affects the backend as well. What it seems to have done is change the endpoints on everything. I got a patched version from Manuel at DevDemon, and it seems to have resolved the issue. Hopefully the next release will officially resolve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out the update seemed to change my S3 location; I updated them to the correct server and they started working again. Latest version of the add-on doesn't seem to have this issue anymore.